# Android Listview - Default Selection not working

Tags: android, listview, android-widget

I hope, my issue would be clear for you from my question title. I have three linear layouts in each row of the list view. One linear layout contains an Imageview and the other two linear layout contains text views. These three linear layouts comprise my list view row. But, to my surprise, the listview default selection(orange colored) does not work when I move the trackball of mouse or when I select it from the phone.

Can anyone guide me resolve this issue.

Any help is appreciated.
Looking forward..

Answer (score 1):

By default, the list selector is drawn behind the currently selected item. If your item layout has an opaque background, the selector cannot be seen.

Try making your list item background transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a background color to your row's layouts?  If so, that color will be the only color you see - even on touch events.

A row's background should really be set to a selectable drawable with different colors for different states like selected and unselected.